# Dual boot issues

Tags: dual-boot

Lost WIN XP in dual boot with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. It hangs but Ubuntu runs OK.

My Fujitsu Scaleo P XP recovery CD does NOT support the Recovery Console and therefore MBR corruption cannot be eradicated in this way with FIXMBR. At first it posted "NTDLR missing" but now it does nothing.

So I chased the Forums and found the Boot recovery software which I was able to download & run on Ubuntu.  The results produce a file which I sent in to here as requested:-  http://paste.ubuntu.com/14992279

From that you will see that the sda1 start point should be sector 63 but is reported as 2048. It would seem that it needs to be adjusted. How do I do that - if indeed that is the correct thing to do?

All the rest of the report seems to agree with what is expected. I can see the WIN XP folders & system files are actually on the disk via File Explorer in Ubuntu.

Can you please tell me how to proceed. As you can imagine I really don't want to re-install XP as I will lose all my settings and as it is no longer supported by MS I may not get the SP3 updates.

Faithfully,
Berry Greene